# HTML button not running .NET code

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am kind of new to the `ASP.NET` programming and I am trying to get some `.NET` code to run behind some HTML code. Someone else wrote the html, I am tasked with getting the buttons working.

Nothing I try is working, the button currently looks like this:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnServerClick="btnSubmit_Click">Submit</button>
```

Code behind the `btnSubmit`looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSubmit.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("test");
}
```

When I go to test it, when I hit the `Submit` button, all that happens is the page refreshes, I don't get the "test" output as I would expect. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Tested your code, it works. The method gets called. And you don't need to bind the click in page load as you already are assigning it on the button.

Comment: @derloopkat every HTML element with runat="server" is a server control. And triggers a postback

Comment: After fooling with this for like 3 hours, I didn't have the runat="server" in the overall <form> tag. Works after adding that. stupid mistakes...

Comment: The basic basic of webform :-)

Comment: I know but didn't see any runatserver first time I read the post.

Comment: @Caveman42 You can post it as an answer to yourself. Could help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced such issues before, simply use the named function.
You don't need to use

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSubmit.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
}
```

When you initialize the button in **runat=server** the server will read it as button thus to be handled while compiling, so simply create a function without any inputs and call it normally. For Example

```
<button runat="server" id="btnAdd" onserverclick="Addition_Func">Add</button>
```

**And in server side:**

```
public void Addition_Func()
{
    try {
//Anycode
} catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```